# Disappearing Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on an access form that  contains a combo box and other controls.
When I click on  button, it calls a subroutine that  builds a table that
populates the combo box. Works great, but the form goes away. When I open
it up, the box looks good, but The form HAS to stay visible. Is there a setting
that I need to set to keep this from happen. Please advise.

```
 Private Sub Command18_Click()
        Load_Contract_Table
 End Sub


 Public Sub Load_Contract_Table()

   Dim daDb As DAO.Database
   Dim rst1 As Recordset
   Dim rst2 As Recordset

   Dim selContract As String

   Set daDb = CurrentDb
   Set rst1 = daDb.OpenRecordset("tblContracts")
   Set rst2 = daDb.OpenRecordset("tblContractList")

   Dim svContract As String
   Dim svID As Integer
   Dim newCont As String
   Set daDb = CurrentDb

    svContract = " "

    st1.MoveFirst

   Do Until rst1.EOF
     If rst1!Contract <> svContract Then
       MsgBox "Contract= " & rst1!Contract
       svContract = rst1!Contract
       svID = rst1!ID
       newCont = rst1!Contract
  
       AddCon newCont, svID
     End If

     rst1.MoveNext
  Loop

 End Sub


 Public Sub AddCon(newCont, svID)
  Dim daDb As DAO.Database
  Dim rst1 As Recordset
  Dim rst2 As Recordset

 Dim selContract As String


Set daDb = CurrentDb
Set rst1 = daDb.OpenRecordset("tblContracts")
Set rst2 = daDb.OpenRecordset("tblContractList")

 rst2.AddNew
 rst2!Contract = newCont
 rst2!ID = svID
 rst2.Update
 rst2.Close

  Set rst2 = Nothing
   DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I put DoCmd.OpenForm at the end of a subroutine and the problem went
away.

Comment: When one problem was solved, another came up.  The combo box was empty, which isn't surprising since the form was closed. I can't believe that I can't retain the contents of a form while a subroutine is running!  Please show  me what I'm missing